# intel driver suppressed after removing NVidia card (switching from NVidia to Intel failed)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics

today, my NVidia graphics card gave up. I removed it from my computer and switched to the on-board one:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I have two systems on this computer: One is Kubuntu 15.04 which used the nouveau driver, before (and never used the proprietary nvidia driver). The other one is a Kubuntu 15.10 which used the proprietary nvidia-352 driver before.

After the removal of the NVidia driver, my Kubuntu 15.04 booted without any trouble and X works fine with two monitors attached and with all 3D effects. I really do *not* need an NVidia card.

However, the Kubuntu 15.10 does not work properly. First, X didn't start at all. So I logged in to the text console (which was fortunately working fine) and I uninstalled all nvidia driver stuff:

```
$ apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

After this, I rebooted and the system still didn't work :-( I found out that the problem was a wrong 'xorg.conf'. It stated (among other things):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout" 
    Screen 0 "nvidia"   
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection
```

I removed the 'Inactive "intel"' line, changed the "nvidia" to "intel" and invoked startx => got a graphical system. I rebooted and the file was wrong again.

After some digging, I found that I have to pass 'nogpumanager' to the kernel, hence I edited '/etc/default/grub', ran 'update-grub' and rebooted => the system booted fine.

However, I saw that some of the desktop effects - e.g. the cube - don't work (they work fine in my Kubuntu 15.04).

The problem seems to be that X uses the 'modesetting' driver instead of the 'intel' driver. I tried to explicitly set 'Driver "intel"' in my 'xorg.conf', but then X does not start :-(

When I run 'Xorg -configure', however, it lists 'intel' as the first line under 'List of video drivers:'!

I assume that my previous installation of the nvidia proprietary driver somehow somewhere forced the intel driver out of the way. However, even after hours of searching, I still didn't find where this problem is located.

In which file does it suppress the intel driver?!

Please help! I really don't want to re-install the system, just because the nvidia driver left some garbage behind (that I was unable to find, so far). And I really would like to use the cube and many other 3D effects again ;-) They seem to be automatically suppressed when using XRender (instead of OpenGL). And I seem not to be able to enable OpenGL when not using the proper driver, even though 'glxinfo' says:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

Also, test programs like 'glxgears' work fine (and even say, I had 2500+ FPS).

Best regards, Marco :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add the output of 'Xorg -configure', because in the end, it says there were no devices to configure, which is obviously nonsense:

https://codewizards.co/mn/tmp/2015-12-07.001/Xorg_configure.log

Comment: ...and here is the output of 'Xorg -configure' on my Kubuntu 15.04 (where the intel driver works fine): https://codewizards.co/mn/tmp/2015-12-07.001/Xorg_configure_functional.log

...and here is the corresponding generated file: https://codewizards.co/mn/tmp/2015-12-07.001/xorg.conf.new

I doubt that this output helps, because the problem is likely that somewhere the intel driver is explicitly suppressed in my Kubuntu 15.10 - and I've got no idea where.

Answer (score 2):

Yabbadabbadoooo!!!! Yeah, I found + fixed it!!!

I figured this problem might somehow be related to the 'alternatives' and after a bit more research, I stumbled over this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/nvidia-current-update-problem/ (at the end)
https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/76

To be sure, I additionally ran this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gl_conf
```

...but this alternative seemed to have not been assigned.

I then removed my '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' again, removed the kernel option 'nogpumanager' from '/etc/default/grub' (followed by 'update-grub') and rebooted.

...and it works fine, now!

Here's (an excerpt of) the output of 'glxinfo':

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Desktop
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
```

With the intel driver now being active, I was able to switch from 'XRender' to 'OpenGL 3.1' (in the display settings under 'Compositor') and all 3D effects work again.

**Edit:** One day later, I saw that LibreOffice didn't start, anymore. I don't have the exact error message anymore, but it said sth. about a missing library - looking related to this problem (and it worked fine before removing NVidia).

After some research, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa:i386
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libglu1
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx
```

I think, only the last line is relevant, but I'm listing all for completeness.

Comment: Thank you marco, I have a similar setup (well same graphics card, same version of Kubuntu, some similar issues).  Your post was helpful.  I just wanted to add, have you tried the Intel Graphics Installer? https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1

Comment: No, I did not try to install anything manually (including this Intel Graphics Installer). I only did the 'update-alternatives' + 'apt-get install' commands documented in my post. And since everything is working fine, I don't really want to try it out - have enough coding to do ;-)